# error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Tags: freebsd, authorize.net, sha256

I have a FreeBSD server
FreeBSD hotspot.brightlan.net 6.2-RELEASE-p6 FreeBSD 6.2-RELEASE-p6 #0: Sat Jul 21 13:42:25 EDT 2007

On this server I have an application in php using curl which connects to Authorize.net through their api. Recently they updated their SSL certificates to support sha256 and hence the SSL certificate also changed. After this change the application is failing to connecting. If I do a 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE)
it connects successfully but I want to go with a full verification of the server during SSL handshake.
I have noted the same gets connected from a different Linux ubuntu server after updating ca certificate file by specifying using CURLOPT_CAINFO option.

But on this FreeBSD, it does not get connected. I have also noted that the SSL certificate is issued on a wildcard character i.e. *.authorize.net. Because of this, on the ubuntu server also, I had to disable CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST. But on this FreeBSD server, it is simply not working with this option even.
The server is a bit old with php version 
PHP 4.4.7 (cgi-fcgi) (built: May  4 2007 13:35:10)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found that the version of the openssl version is behind the problem. SHA256 was not supported until 0.9.8o. So I tried upgrading openssl to latest one. As my system is quite old, latest versions are not being supported. 
So I started compiling 0.9.8o successfully but it breaks SSH as is internally used. So my objective now is to upgrade openssl to 0.9.8o without breaking SSH server.

I started digging down a bit and found out ways to link different version of Openssl as was also mentioned by "Steffen Ullrich" above. I was able to compile and link with openssl 0.9.8o both statically and dynamically and found below observation.

when we compile php with openssl enabled, curl does not use its linked openssl to connect to the site. Here I had compiled both php as well as curl with separate versions of openssl(I have even tried compiling and linking curl with static openssl). The version of openssl which was compiled with php use to take precedence while connecting to the site and hence fails to connect in my case(due to SHA256 ssl certificate & php-openssl-0.9.7e). 
However, if I recompile php with higher version of openssl(0.9.8o), then it is able to connect.

Also, if I compile php without enabling openssl, then curl is able to connect as it uses its linked openssl 0.9.8o.

I do not know if this is a bug or was meant to be like this in php, or maybe fixed in latest available versions of php/curl.

But I think from curl's perspective, it is not the correct thing to use the version of openssl linked with php for connecting to the site. It should use its linked openssl version(0.9.8o) for connecting to the site. While if anybody is connecting to the website the version of openssl(0.9.7e) linked to php should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your are running a very old system which is no longer supported and has probably accumulated lots of security issues. I'm not sure, but I think this version of FreeBSD comes with openssl 0.9.7 which is too old to support certificates signed with SHA-256.

Check your version with `openssl version` and see https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1499561-sha-256-compatibility

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know its an old system and I figured out already that I need to upgrade openssl. I did that also, and works fine on a similar(test) setup. Now the difficulty, now is to link this to only curl so that it does not break others. for example, it breaks ssh service if I link it. I do not want to break things on the production system.

Comment: There are build options when compiling openssl to specify the installation path so that it does not conflict with the systems installation.  And curl seems to have similar options where you can specify the path of the SSL library to use. If you combine these you can build curl with a custom SSL which does not infer with the local installation. Please look into the relevant source distributions for files like INSTALL which usually describe this process in more detail.